# Check internet connection status using proxy

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, winapi, windows-api-code-pack

I would like to check the internet connection(**not Network**) status using proxy.

I dont want to ping any urls.

For that I used IsConnectedToInternet property of NetworkListManagerClass(Interop.NETWORKLIST.dll),

IsConnectedToInternet  works fine for both positive and negative scenarios.

But how I can set the proxy details to NetworkListManagerClass.

Comment: `INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY` in [InternetGetConnectedState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate#parameters). Please check if it is useful.

Comment: INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY is the return value, Not the proxy value that we can set to api call. Moreover In MSDN mentioned not recommended to use this api.

Comment: Yes, the doc recommended to use the `INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity` which returns the overall connectivity state of the machine. By the way, what proxy values do you need to set?  I think you can set the proxy value before using the API, and then use the API to check the internet connection.

Comment: like WebReequest, these apis no mechanisms to set proxy details.

Comment: Check: [Setting WinINet Proxy Configurations in WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/setting-wininet-proxy-configurations-in-winhttp)